# How to split a String using multiple delimeters

Tags: vb.net, string, split, delimiter

I'm using a very particular program that doesn't have many pre loaded functions on it. I would like to split a Date and time into individual variables. 6 variables to be exact

I get the date and time like this 5/28/2014 15:34:40 so I have 3 characters "/" " " and ":" separating the 6 variables I want, but I can only get one to work at a time. I have tried many other ways but the x.Split() is the only syntax that this program seems to like (PARCView).

```
Dim x as String = "5/28/2014 15:34:40"
Dim y as String() = x.Split(New Char() {":"c})
```

So how can I add all three at once or use consecutive steps to store each number as a unique variable?

Comment: @Selman22, Syntax looks like visual basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have the [Char Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you need, though it only has one delineator... just fill it with the other delineators and it will split it for you.

```
Dim y As String() = x.Split(New Char() {":"c, "/"c, " "c})
```

example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works as well. As soon As i posted this I found similar answer. I just had to take my eyes off the screen.

Comment: I used this:
Dim sep() as Char = {" "c, ":"c,"/"c}
Dim y as String() = x.Split(sep)

Comment: @Mitch0492 Yes, that will work also, I am just doing it inline since that is what your example was showing. you were creating a character array and only putting one delineator in it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to parse it as a datetime object which will contain all the parts as properties:

```
Dim teststr = "5/28/2014 15:34:40"
Dim dt = DateTime.Parse(teststr)
```

Comment: Well, you should use `ParseExact` really but this is a better method

Comment: How then do I extract the elements of the date?

Comment: The datetime properties contain all the elements, day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.